# Multiply two Dataframes if the column names and the condition on a column value matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two dataframes(namely `a` and `b`):

`a =`

[image]

and `b =`

[image]

And I am looking for a way to multiply the values in each column of Dataframe `a` with the corresponding column value of Dataframe `b` if the dates are matching. For example:values in column `aa_10` of Dataframe `a` for the date `2021-01-19` with the corresponding value in column `aa_10` of Dataframe `b` for the date `2021_01_19` (i.e., the column- `NaN, 2.0, 3.0,4.0` of Dataframe `a` to be multiplied with the value `4` in Dataframe `b`) and so on.

*Desired result:*

[image]

**Sample Data:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
  
d = {'Date'  : pd.Series([20210119, 20210119, 20210119, 20210119, 20210122, 20210122, 20210122, 20210122]),
     'To'  : pd.Series(['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']),
     'aa_10' : pd.Series([np.nan, 2, 3, 4, np.nan, 4, 3, 2]),
     'bb_11' : pd.Series([6, np.nan, 8, 9, 9, np.nan, 7, 8]),
     'cc_12' : pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan, 4, 4, 3, np.nan, 5]),
     'dd_13' : pd.Series([6, 7, 8, np.nan, 8, 6, 9, np.nan])}
  
# creates Dataframe.
a = pd.DataFrame(d)
a['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(a['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
# print the data.
display (a)

# Initialize data to Dicts of series.
d = {'Date'  : pd.Series([20190110, 20210119, 20210121, 20210122]),
     'aa_10' : pd.Series([2, 4, 1, 2]),
     'bb_11' : pd.Series([1, 3, 5, 4]),
     'cc_12' : pd.Series([10, 12, 4, 2]),
     'dd_13' : pd.Series([2, 1, 2, 5])}
  
# creates Dataframe.
b = pd.DataFrame(d)
b['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(b['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')  
# print the data.
display(b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set_index as date and multiply

```
s=a.set_index(['Date', 'To']).mul(b.set_index(['Date'])).reset_index()




   Date  To  aa_10  bb_11  cc_12  dd_13
0 2021-01-19  aa    NaN   18.0   12.0    6.0
1 2021-01-19  bb    8.0    NaN   24.0    7.0
2 2021-01-19  cc   12.0   24.0    NaN    8.0
3 2021-01-19  dd   16.0   27.0   48.0    NaN
4 2021-01-22  aa    NaN   36.0    8.0   40.0
5 2021-01-22  bb    8.0    NaN    6.0   30.0
6 2021-01-22  cc    6.0   28.0    NaN   45.0
7 2021-01-22  dd    4.0   32.0   10.0    NaN
```

Comment: thank you @wwnde . I just added the Desired result Dataframe. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: Ok, edited the answer for you

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `reindex` , then `mul` the value and `update` your original `a`

```
b_n = b.set_index('Date').reindex(a.Date)
b_n.index = a.index
a.update(a.mul(b_n))
a
        Date  To  aa_10  bb_11  cc_12  dd_13
0 2021-01-19  aa    NaN   18.0   12.0    6.0
1 2021-01-19  bb    8.0    NaN   24.0    7.0
2 2021-01-19  cc   12.0   24.0    NaN    8.0
3 2021-01-19  dd   16.0   27.0   48.0    NaN
4 2021-01-22  aa    NaN   36.0    8.0   40.0
5 2021-01-22  bb    8.0    NaN    6.0   30.0
6 2021-01-22  cc    6.0   28.0    NaN   45.0
7 2021-01-22  dd    4.0   32.0   10.0    NaN
```